# Is there a site to ask about speaking problem?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I tend to lack coherence and get stumble when talking in thoughtful topics. Unless I really take note, cat always got my tongue, even thought I know what to say. My writing is, nonetheless, not having that problem.

Where should I ask such question? Since most thoughtful topics I meet are in academic setting, I think that asking this question on Academia is on-topic. But I'm afraid that it may be considered to be a boat programming question there.

---

**Example**: say I need to talk about game theory to persuade a speaker. I have read about it, and I know that to successfully persuade them, I need to use point a and b. When I thinking about what to talk in my head, both a and b are thought carefully enough to the point that I believe that they will work. However, when I don't take note and get straight to speak, cat got my tongue and eventually point a is spoken in a way that it's hard to understand, and I completely forgot point b.

This is the extreme case, I not always get to this level of this problem.

Comment: Can you give a specific question you want to ask?

Comment: More people have this problem. Maybe a professional coach / therapist would be more useful than a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Close Voter(s): please note that this is a site-recommendation question. I do not think it is "Too Broad".

Comment: @PatrickHofman added

Comment: @S.L.Barth do you have any keyword for me to search efficiently?

Comment: @S.L.Barth it was since there can be a million questions, and without clear-cut question, it is impossible to give a precise answer. Reverted the close vote now since the question is to the point now.

Comment: Is English your first language?

Comment: @TravisJ no, it's not. The problem is that I have this problem even in my first language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Public Speaking](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92010/public-speaking) proposal on Area 51 may be of interest. It's currently in the definition phase.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a site fitting your question, how to overcome speaking problems isn't a subject that can be found in Area51 or any live site at the moment. Indeed, if your question is related to academia, it might be on-topic on Academia.SE, but I won't really suggest that. Maybe you can post on their meta and check if they like the question.

In my opinion, speaking problems need very specific help, and a professional can probably help you better with this.

Comment: For those interested: I have asked my question in the Meta Academia: [Is the question about speaking problem on-topic?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/2121/14341)

Comment: So that is a no?